# Pytumblr Not authorized when creating posts

Tags: python, api, oauth, tumblr

My pytumblr version is 0.0.6, the one in the repo. Imports work properly. I'm using Python 2.7.8, with that said:

I have logged into my account.
I went to https://api.tumblr.com/console
I have put the `consumer_key` & `consumer_secret` keys
I have allowed it and
I have copied this code:

```
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    'my_consumer_key',
    'my_consumer_secret',
    'my_access_token',
    'my_token_secret'
)
```

Then I have tried to create a text post. The next code is taken from the pytumblr github readme page. I've just added the response code.

```
response = client.create_text("codingjester", state="published", slug="testing-text-posts", title="Testing", body="testing1 2 3 4")
print(response)
```

But, this is what it say...

```
{u'meta': {u'status': 401, u'msg': u'Not Authorized'}, u'response': []}
```

**¿ Why ?**

**Ps:** Doing other oauth call like `client.followers("blogname")` works, but not when trying to post as I have said above.

**EDIT:** I tried to use three legged oauth authorization. With Selenium to automate the http request to get the `oauth_verifier` and then get the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` with this and the `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret` should be enough to use pytumblr... **But I'm still getting the 401 Not Authorized response :(** Oh, and I'm using "http://localhost/" as my callback_url, otherwise or with just "/" the autorization url doesn't return the oauth_verifier key

Here's the code:

```
import urlparse
import oauth2 as oauth
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

consumer_key = 'my_consumer_key'
consumer_secret = 'my_consumer_secret'

callback_url = 'http://localhost/'
request_token_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
access_token_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token'
authorize_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize'

consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

# Step 1: Get a request token. This is a temporary token that is used for
# having the user authorize an access token and to sign the request to obtain
# said access token.

resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")
if resp['status'] != '200':
    raise Exception("Invalid response %s." % resp['status'])

request_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Request Token:"
print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % request_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % request_token['oauth_token_secret']
print

# Step 2: HERE's WHAT I HAVE MODIFIED. I USE SELENIUM TO GET THE oauth_verifier

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://www.tumblr.com/login")

wait1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
u = wait1.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'my_username';", u)

p = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='password']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'my_password';", p)

p.submit()

time.sleep(10)
driver.get("http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + request_token['oauth_token'])
time.sleep(5)
allow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button)[2]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", allow)
time.sleep(5)

a = driver.current_url

a = a.replace(callback_url + '?oauth_token=' + request_token['oauth_token'] + "&oauth_verifier=", "")
a = a.replace("#_=_", "")

print(a)

oauth_verifier = a

# Step 3: Once the consumer has redirected the user back to the oauth_callback
# URL you can request the access token the user has approved. You use the
# request token to sign this request. After this is done you throw away the
# request token and use the access token returned. You should store this
# access token somewhere safe, like a database, for future use.
token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'],
    request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
token.set_verifier(oauth_verifier)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)

resp, content = client.request(access_token_url, "POST")
access_token = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(content))

print "Access Token:"
print "    - oauth_token        = %s" % access_token['oauth_token']
print "    - oauth_token_secret = %s" % access_token['oauth_token_secret']
print
print "You may now access protected resources using the access tokens above."
print

client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    consumer_key,
    consumer_secret,
    access_token['oauth_token'],
    access_token['oauth_token_secret'],
)
response = client.create_text("codingjester", state="published", slug="testing-text-posts", title="Testing", body="testing1 2 3 4")
print(response)
```

Maybe would be better to learn how to issue a pure oauth requests using the endpoint... and desist using the pytumblr wrapper... I'm starting to think that it sucks and that is really unmaintained library.

Answer (score 1):

```
response = client.create_text("**codingjester**", state="published", slug="testing-text-posts", title="Testing", body="testing1 2 3 4")
```

But is "codingjester" actually your blog? otherwise it is right to get not authorized.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument for `client.create_text` or `client.create_photo` needs to be the blogname of your blog, so for a photo, do:

```
client.create_photo('yourblogname', 'stringlinktolocalfileorURL')
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I fixed by hard-coding the oauth_token and oauth_token_secret (obtained from https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/user/info) rather than using the request_token calls. Perhaps whatever is going wrong with those calls can be fixed but in the meantime hard-coding works as a workaround.

Taken from: http://yuluer.com/page/bgfbhjgf-python-tumblr-api-cannot-log-in-to-my-own-tumblr-to-create-posts.shtml